# Why my java elasticsearch request translation is not valid?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-query

I'm currently making an elasticsearch request to retrieves some data. I have succeeded to write the right request in Json format. After that I tried to translate this one into Java. But when I print the request that the Java sends to ES, both requests are not the same and I don't achieve to make that.

Here is the Json request that returns the GOOD data:

```
{
    "query": {
         "filtered": {
             "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
              },
              "filter": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                        { "terms": { "accountId": ["107276450147"] } },
                        {"range" : {
                             "date" : {
                                 "lt" : "1480612801000",
                                 "gte" : "1478020801000"
                         } }
                     }]
                 }
             }
         }
     },
    "size" : 0,
    "aggregations" : {
        "field-aggregation" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "publicationId",
                "size" : 2147483647
            },
            "aggregations" : {
                "top-aggregation" : {
                    "top_hits" : {
                        "size" : 1,
                        "_source" : {
                            "includes" : [ ],
                            "excludes" : [ ]
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

And the Java generated request... which does not return good data..

```
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 10,
    "aggregations" : {
        "field-aggregation" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "publicationId",
                "size" : 2147483647
            },
            "aggregations" : {
                "top-aggregation" : {
                    "top_hits" : {
                        "size" : 1,
                        "_source" : {
                            "includes" : [ ],
                            "excludes" : [ ]
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

And finally the java code that generate the wrong json request:

```
TopHitsBuilder top = AggregationBuilders.topHits("top-aggregation")
        .setFetchSource(true)
        .setSize(1);

    TermsBuilder field = AggregationBuilders.terms("field-aggregation")
        .field(aggFieldName)
        .size(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .subAggregation(top);

    BoolFilterBuilder filterBuilder = FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
        .must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("accountId", Collections.singletonList("107276450147")))
        .must(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("date").gte(1478020801000L).lte(1480612801000L));

    NativeSearchQueryBuilder query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), filterBuilder))
        .withIndices("metric")
        .withTypes(type)
        .addAggregation(field);

return template.query(query.build());
```

First of all, I must remove the "size":10 and the "from" that the Java generates... And after I have to add the filters. I did this but it's never added..
Can you tell what is wrong in my java code and why the filters does not appears in the final Json?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Just quick thing, why do you want to remove `size` and `from`? ES will automatically use defaults then which is equivalent to `"from" : 0, "size" : 10`

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I finally manage the problem. The java sent the good query but I was looked at the wrong place in ES java API. Nevertheless, I added the request type to COUNT in order to avoid ES send me back the non-aggregated data that are useless for me.